# MPEG-4 part 10 video not working flowplayer html5?

Tags: html, video, flowplayer

I am using mpeg4 video format in my site.It only working chrome.Not working ipad and ie.But the format is mpeg4 part 10 H.264 encoding.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the correct encoding of your video. For browsers it should be: Baseline Level 3.

You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert your videos using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -codec:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -profile:v baseline -level 3 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

- Control quality with `-crf` and encoding speed with `-preset` as shown in the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide).
- For audio encoding recommendations see the [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide).
- `-pix_fmt yuv420p` will ensure that your output will use a chroma subsampled pixel format that is supported by the browser.
- `-movflags faststart` will relocate the moov atom after encoding completes which allows the video to begin playback before it is completely downloaded by the client.

Comment: which converting tool is best for this encoding?